# Нужна ли точка после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

*Добавляем: «Вывел на рынок новую модель кедов серии Air Max и за 4 месяца добился продаж в объеме 16,7 млн руб.»(.)*

Вроде как точка при сокращении слова "рубль" не является знаком конца предложения, однако если предложение бы стояло отдельно, то такая точка бы поглотила точку в конце предложения.

*Вывел на рынок новую модель кедов серии Air Max и за 4 месяца добился продаж в объеме 16,7 млн руб.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужна.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178)**:

> Точка повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она
>   употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: В
>   объявлении было сказано: «Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы,
>   стулья, диваны и т. д.».

[**Правила набора текстов:**](http://www.docwriter.ru/info/rules/)

> Точка после сокращения в конце предложения обычно не дублируется:
>   «Первый, второй и т. д.». Тем не менее, если сокращение с точкой
>   заключено в кавычки или скобки, точка в конце предложения ставится:
>   «Необходимо установить полный комплект (8 шт.)».

**[Валгина:](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-033.htm)**

При сочетании разных знаков препинания с кавычками действует ряд правил:

> перед закрывающей кавычкой не ставится точка, запятая, тире,
>   двоеточие, точка с запятой; эти знаки возможны лишь после кавычек:
>   *«Я-то уж наверно не откажусь», - сказала Маргарита* (Булг.); Пришвин однажды написал о себе (в частном письме), что он *«поэт, распятый на
>   кресте прозы». «Где граница между прозой и поэзией,* - писал Лев
>   Толстой, - *я никогда не пойму»* (Пауст.); *Когда я резвился со своим
>   «Зорким» двадцать пять лет назад, магазины были завалены отличной
>   немецкой пленкой «Агфа»; теперь же, когда я спросил «Агфу», в магазине
>   все, и продавцы и покупатели, теснящиеся у прилавка, дружно и весело
>   рассмеялись* (Сол.). **Точка возможна лишь при сокращении слова, тогда
>   она оказывается внутри выделяемого кавычками компонента**: *Здесь было
>   две статьи: одна - Латунского, а другая - подписанная буквами «Н.
>   Э.». Уверяю вас, что произведения Аримана и Лавровича могли считаться
>   шуткою по сравнению с написанным Латунским* (Булг.).

**[Грамота.ру:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=275448)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

**Добавляем: «Вывел на рынок новую модель кедов серии Air Max и за 4 месяца добился продаж в объеме 16,7 млн руб.».**

> Точка повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: В объявлении было сказано: «Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы, стулья, диваны и т. д.».([§ 66. Кавычки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175))