# «И т. д. » в прямой речи. Запятая после ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

*«Нужно побелить потолки, стены и т. д.», – сказал директор школы.*
Нужно ли ставить запятую после сокращения с точкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится. Даже если бы  кавычкой заканчивалось предложение, после неё ставилась бы точка по общему правилу: *Директор сказал: "Нужно побелить потолки, стены и т. д.".* Этот вопрос рассматривался [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440121/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5).
Обратите внимание — между сокращёнными словами должен быть пробел: *и т. д.*